# Cublas - Column/Row wise operations

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust, cublas

I am looking for a way to perform operations over columns .
I have MxN matrix, i want to activate cublas function (for example nrm2) over each column.

The result i expect to get is : M x 1

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

CUBLAS has no batched Level 1 routines, so there is no direct way to compute the column or row norms in a single call. You can do it by calling nrm2 many times in a loop over all the rows or columns of the matrix, for example:

```
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

struct prg
{
    float a, b;

    __host__ __device__
    prg(float _a=0.f, float _b=1.f) : a(_a), b(_b) {};

    __host__ __device__
        float operator()(const unsigned int n) const
        {
            thrust::default_random_engine rng;
            thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(a, b);
            rng.discard(n);

            return dist(rng);
        }
};


int main(void)
{
    const int M = 1024, N = M;
    const int num = N * M;

    thrust::device_vector<float> matrix(num);
    thrust::device_vector<float> vector(N, -1.0f);
    thrust::counting_iterator<unsigned int> index_sequence_begin(0);

    thrust::transform(index_sequence_begin,
            index_sequence_begin + num,
            matrix.begin(),
            prg(1.f,2.f));

    float* m_d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(matrix.data());
    float* v_d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(vector.data());

    cudaStream_t stream; 
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);

    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);
    cublasSetPointerMode(handle, CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_DEVICE);
    cublasSetStream(handle, stream);

    for(int col=0; col < N; col++) {
        cublasSnrm2(handle, M, m_d + col*M, 1, v_d + col);
    }
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for(auto x : vector) {
        float normval = x;
        std::cout << normval << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Unless you have very large rows or columns, there is little scope to exploit streams to run simultaneous kernels and reduce the overall runtime because each nrm2 call will be too short. So there is a lot of latency in running lots of individual kernels, which will negatively effect performance.

A much better alternative would be to write your own kernel to do this.

Comment: I need help building up a kernel. My dimension are large M, and small N (3).

I know that the best for me is to run M threads, but i cant understand numBlocks and threads per block

Comment: A comment on the end of an answer to a different question isn't the place to ask for help. In fact  [SO] isn't a place to ask for help. It is a place to ask questions. and receive answers. Subtle but important difference. And "Can somebody help me?" isn't an appropriate question. Keep that in mind, do some research on you problem and come back and ask a new question when you are ready. That is how [SO] works.